# How to Test Timeout Interceptor in Nestjs Using Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I can't find any explanation on how to test interceptors in NestJS.

Please help me to test the Interceptor using jest?

```js
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler, RequestTimeoutException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Observable, throwError, TimeoutError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, timeout } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(private readonly interval: number) {}

    intercept(_context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        if (this.interval > 0) {
            return next.handle().pipe(
                timeout(this.interval),
                catchError((error) => {
                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        return throwError(new RequestTimeoutException(`The operation timed out. `));
                    }
                    return throwError(error);
                }),
            );
        }
        return next.handle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write unit tests for this interceptor once but I didn't like it :/ Look: https://gist.github.com/micalevisk/33d793202541f044d8f5bccb81049b94

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find similar issues out there, hoping that anyone would be willing to answer but I still got nothing until today. Nevertheless, I try to figure it out all alone. For someone out there who's probably looking for a possible workaround.

Let's take a look at the simple timeout interceptor example from nestjs [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#more-operators)

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler, RequestTimeoutException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError, TimeoutError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      timeout(5000),
      catchError(err => {
        if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
          return throwError(() => new RequestTimeoutException());
        }
        return throwError(() => err);
      }),
    );
  };
};
```

The possible unit test to test the error inside the observable is to **mock the return value after a specified time (delay)**. In this case, **it would be more than 5000**. This can be achieved by utilizing the [delay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delay) rxjs operator.

So the appropriate unit test for this timeout interceptor would be something similar to this.

```
describe('TimeoutInterceptor', () => {
  const executionContext = mockedExecutionContext; // your mocked execution context
  const callHandler = mockedCallHandler; // your mocked call handler

  let timeoutInterceptor: TimeoutInterceptor;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [TimeoutInterceptor],
    }).compile();

    timeoutInterceptor = moduleRef.get<TimeoutInterceptor>(TimeoutInterceptor);
  });

  describe('when intercept is called', () => {
    const returnedValue: [] = [];

    describe('and the request time is not exceeded the max allowed timeout in ms', () => {
      it(`should return the to be returned value`, (done: any) => {
        callHandler.handle.mockReturnValue(
          of(returnedValue).pipe(
            delay(2500), // below 5000
          ),
        );

        timeoutInterceptor.intercept(executionContext, callHandler).subscribe({
          next(value) {
            expect(value).toStrictEqual(returnedValue);
          },
          complete() {
            done();
          },
        });
      });
    });

    describe('and the request time exceeded (+1000ms) the max allowed timeout in ms', () => {
      it(`should throw ${RequestTimeoutException.name}`, (done: any) => {
        callHandler.handle.mockReturnValue(
          of(returnedValue).pipe(delay(5000 + 1000)), // 5000 + 1000ms
        );

        timeoutInterceptor.intercept(executionContext, callHandler).subscribe({
          error(err) {
            expect(err).toBeInstanceOf(RequestTimeoutException);
            done(); // don't forget to invoke this done, or the test will be hang
          },
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```